# Ember.JS and ember-data throwing cryptic error messages when using Router

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a saved search feature for an Ember application, with the general idea being that after conducting a search you have the option to enter a shortname for the search and save it to `localStorage` and retrieve it later from a dropdown list, while also being able to share the current URL with other users and have them see the same search.

This works through a combination of the Ember `Router` handling search params in the URL and a view that handles the user clicking 'save' (the view is included in a fiddle, but is not able to be run as no templates are included -- see below).

Whenever I run the application, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined
```

You can see the trace in the fiddle listed below, however it appears to stem from the controller store injection in ember-data. Unfortunately my knowledge of Ember[-data] doesn't extend far enough to know how this relates to the rest of the application.

I've taken the relevant parts of the application that should work independently and run them in a JSFiddle, but that still results in the same error. The fiddle is located at http://jsfiddle.net/fetcU/. Currently there are no handlebars templates or anything in that fiddle as they don't contribute to the problem.

The `localStorage` adapter and other parts worked fine independently until the Router was introduced, and so it may be related to the code now being run by `Checklist.initialize()` (which wasn't necessary until the Router was added).

I've compared this to other similar projects and examples, particularly those given for ember-data, and it's not entirely clear what I'm doing wrong here. I'd appreciate any insight!

Comment: I would help you, but jsfiddle is down now :(

Comment: Hah, bad timing from JSFiddle. It appears to be back up now, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try making your controller a class? So, instead of Checklist.savedSearchController, try Checklist.SavedSearchController.

Comment: That's what I mean, I think I've not beeing explicit enough. In his code, he has somme issues like that

Answer (score 3):

First thing: When you create an app with a router, you don't have to create instances of Store, Controllers, Views. When calling App.initialize(), ember will do the instantiation and injection for you.

Then, you will have access:

- controllers, via the router (in the connectOutlets()), by router.get(xxxController), where xxx is for example application (to access the base controller), or savedSearch to access your savedSearchController.
- the store, from the router by invoking router.get('store')
- a xxxController from a xxxView by invoking this.get('controller'), or from the templates with view.controller
- the router from the controllers, by invoking this.get('target')

Well, I let you try modifying the code. Let me now when you are stuck again :)

Comment: I came across @tygirl76's solution accidentally myself while fiddling with your suggestions, so I've marked that answer as correct for other people to see. Thanks for the help, you've actually helped me convert a lot of my code to the "ember way" rather than using hacky methods to get controllers, etc. from other locations.

Comment: Thx for the +1 :). When your fiddle is ready, I you want I could review it